# Cannot bind text field to selected item in JTable in NetBeans

Tags: data-binding, netbeans, jtable, javabeans

I am trying to use NetBeans to bind a JTextField to the selected element of a JTable.

The JTable gets its data from an AbstractTableModel subclass which returns Cow objects.  At present, each Cow object is displayed as a String through its toString method.

I am trying to bind the **text** property of the JTextField to the **name** property of the Cow object which is selected in the JTable.

I bound the text property of the JTextField in NetBeans to:

`flowTable[${selectedElement.name}]`

This produces the following line of generated code:

```
org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = 
  org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(
    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, 
    cowTable, 
    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.name}"), 
    cowNameTextField, 
    org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
```

The bound value of the text field is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post more code (your tablemodel, table...)

Comment: I am no longer working on this project for which I ended up not using NetBeans bindings at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Cow` class have a `public String getName()` method returning the name?

If it doesn't, the outcome you're getting would be expected. If it does, could you post more code (your data class, tablemodel, table...).

Answer (score 0):

If you only are interested in a String in the table, and not the Cow object itself:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
             Object value = table.getValueAt(e.getFirstIndex(), COLUMN_X);
             jTextField.setText(value.toString());
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: hello , what do you mean by COLUMN_X ... is that referring to a constant column number that I am supposed to bind the text field with  ?

Answer (score 0):

Does your Cow class support adding a `PropertyChangeListener`? I did not use the beans binding support from NetBeans that often, but I remember you needed it. Anyway, a little more code could help with finding out whats going wrong.